# Parallel ajax requests or sql queries? [performance aspect]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, postgresql

I am designing and implementing property management system and I have dashboard which contains rooms' bookings for specified date intervals.

What am I asking, is related to performance [loading rooms' information].
Currently, I have

```
for (var r = 0; r < rooms.length; r++)
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/dashboard/getAllOrders.php',
        data: 'room_id=' + encodeURIComponent(rooms[r].id),
        complete: function (e, xhr, settings) {
            if (e.status === 200)
            {
                var orders = $.parseJSON(e.responseText);
                for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++)
                {
                    drawOrder(orders[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        });
    }
```

But, I can also write it as:

```
var room_ids = [];
    for (var r = 0; r < rooms.length; r++)
    {
        room_ids.push(rooms[r].id);
    }

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/dashboard/getAllRoomsOrders.php',
    data: { 'room_ids' : room_ids },
    complete: function(event, request, settings)
    {
        if (event.status === 200)
        {

            var orders = $.parseJSON(event.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++)
            {
                drawOrder(orders[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    });
```

Could you recommend me which option do I need to to stick with and provide arguments which will prove why one option is better, than other, from performance point of view?

If not, could you recommend the best benchmarking practices for client-server applications?

Comment: The second is much better, assuming you do the right thing and combine it into a single sql query on the back end. less network traffic, less db queries sent, etc. not sure how this is even a question.

Comment: Looking at it another way, Lets say you need milk and bread from the store. What's faster/more efficient? Sending one person in one car to get both at once, or sending two people in two different cars to get it? The difference will be small with just 2 items, but it's clearly going to have bandwidth issues if you needed 50+ items.

Comment: I almost agree with you. But we need 50+ cars, instead of one, right? It will eat more memory which must be allocated, and memory allocating beside it eats resources, also needs time to be allocated, no? in C++, dynamic memory is slower than, auto static memory. Ok, maybe I will try to make some benchmarks, to see which option is faster.

Comment: well, no, unless i misunderstood what you mean, i'm saying it's faster to send 1 car for 50 items than 50, because if you sent 50 there's going to be traffic (bandwidth) problems getting to the store, getting through the checkout lines, and getting back to the house (memory management, network bandwidth, i/o limits, etc.) Of course, there's upper limits to the 1 car 50 item approach, but that's easily fixed with batching (which is what we're doing basically)

Comment: It's far faster to send a sql query that gets 50 items than it is to send 50 sql queries each getting 1 item. that difference will be MUCH smaller with just 2 items, however it should still be faster to send a single query.

Comment: Yes, for tree rooms 1.78 times faster,  and for two rooms 1.63 times faster. I made benchmarks. For fifty rooms performance will be degraded if not 50 times, but still very catastrophically. Thank you, and please, make you comment as an answer, so I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may see little to no difference for very small amounts of data, however, as the number of roomId's increases, you'll begin to see the first approach taking longer than the second mostly due to bandwidth.

By combining all of these requests into a single request, you are reducing the amount of network traffic between the client and the webserver and the webserver and the db server because in both cases combining the request removes the need to repeatedly send header data and sql queries and instead sends them once thus reducing network traffic and db lookups.